# Testing controller - record not found when using find with includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, include, rspec

I'm testing a controller action that uses includes in the find statement.  It raises RecordNotFound when the test runs.  Am I missing something?  How should I be handling tests on such things?

Controller:

```
def show
  @forum_sub_topic = ForumSubTopic.includes(:forum_posts => [:post_replies]).find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @forum_sub_topic }
  end
end
```

Test:

```
it 'renders show template' do
  ForumSubTopic.stub(:find).with("37") { mock_forum_sub_topic }
  get :show, :id => "37"
  response.should render_template('show')
ebd
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're stubbing `:find` on `ForumSubTopic`, but your controller is calling `.find` on an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object rather than the `ForumSubTopic` model.

If you don't care so much about the `with("37")` part (because I'm not sure if it's possible doing this), RSpec provides a `stub_chain` method that should work for you:

```
ForumSubTopic.stub_chain(:includes, :find) { mock_forum_sub_topic }
```

Otherwise, you could put multiple stubs in:

```
ForumSubTopic.stub(:includes) { ForumSubTopic }
ForumSubTopic.stub(:find).with("37") { mock_forum_sub_topic }
```

Comment: Thats all I neeed, thanks :)   The chain method is more sleek, I will use that